# Metaphor or Hyperbole: The strength given by my mother is bigger than the cosmic energy in this cosmos

Tags: metaphors, hyperbole

This question appeared on a verbal test. I could only mark one option but I think both of them are a good fit.
This is a metaphor as there is a comparison between two unlike things. This should also be a hyperbole as mother's strength is obviously not greater than the energy of cosmos.
Kindly tell me which literary device is an apt fit and MORE IMPORTANTLY give reasons why the other option is wrong.
Thanks

Comment: It is a hyperbole.

Comment: Something can be both a metaphor and hyperbole.  This is both, though the hyperbole is much stronger.

Comment: You are correct. It is a poor question, though doubtless they want the answer 'hyperbole' as this is the answer requiring less subtle reasoning. Look up 'metaphor' and 'Lawler' together here to find details of say 'the container metaphor' for the more learned approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A metaphor is when you liken something to something different from it, because there's some quality they have in common.

> The snow is a white blanket.

Your example is not a metaphor because strength and energy are very similar things, often used synonymously in casual speech or writing.

But it is hyperbole, because it's an exaggeration of the amount of energy your mother gave you.

However, there's also something metaphoric about it, because emotional strength and cosmic energy are very different forms of energy.

Comment: There _is_ a metaphor; emotional support is referenced in the common 'energy is inner resilience' metaphor, where resilience itself is metaphoric. Energy etc are fundamentally physical properties.

Comment: You're right, I was thinking of strength inherited genetically, not emotional strength.